# How do i add linting package for jquery in Sublime text 3?

Tags: jquery, sublimetext2, sublimetext3, jslint, sublime-jslint

i have installed the package called jslint but its look like it is not supporting for jQuery. How do i checking error on jquery with sublime text 3? Kindly help.

Comment: Did that answer fix your problem? Or did you see jQuery specific errors when you ran JSLint? If it's the second, you probably need a JSLint directive at the top of your files. It's impossible to tell from your broad question, but if Aniruddh's got your answer, best of luck, I guess!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

https://github.com/SublimeLinter/SublimeLinter3

http://www.paraesthesia.com/archive/2013/02/12/how-to-set-up-jshint-in-sublime-text-2-using.aspx/

SublimeLinter is perhaps what you're looking for. The second link has instructions for using it with jQuery.

Does that help?